# Angles in Chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I want to draw this formula using chemfig:

[image: BCA Cu+ Complex]

This is what I've got so far:

```
\chemfig{Cu^+(-[:180]N**6(-**6(------)--(-OOC-)---))(-[1]N)(-[5]N)(-[7]N)}
```

[image: my try]

I don't get the angle from N to Cu+ right. I tried to rotate parts of the formula, but there is always at least one angle that does not fit.

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I have an idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\definesubmol\cc{**6(---!\ff-!\ee--)}
\definesubmol\dd{**6(-!\ee--!\ff---)}
\definesubmol\ee{**6(-----)}
\definesubmol\ff[(-^{-}OOC)]{(-COO^{-})}
\chemfig{Cu^+(-[1]N([0,.5]!\cc))(-[3]N([:180,.5]!\dd))(-[5]N([:180,.5]!\cc))(-[7]N([:0,.5]!\dd))}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following code is similar to what unbonpetit wrote. The term `.5` in `[0,.5]` and `[180,.5]` is chosen such that the aromatic cycles do not get too big.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{Cu^+
(-[:+ 45]N([0,.5]**6(---(-COO^{-})-**6(------)--)))
(-[:+135]N([180,.5]**6(-**6(------)--(-^{-}OOC)---)))
(-[:+225]N([180,.5]**6(---(-^{-}OOC)-**6(------)--)))
(-[:+315]N([0,.5]**6(-**6(------)--(-COO^{-})---)))}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @unbonpetit: I don't see the point...

Comment: It is not exactly the same since your inner ring has 6 bonds instead of 5. Moreover, your code is not more or less explicit than mine, even after several edits.

Comment: I must admit that the term "explicit" is misleading.